# child class method's output not printing?

Tags: java

when I called printThread, why is it printing 0 and 3?

```
class Super {

    Super() { 
        three(); 
    }

    void three() { 
        System.out.println("three"); 
    }
}

class Child extends Super {
    int three = (int) Math.PI;  // That is, 3

    void three() { 
        System.out.println(three); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child t = new Child();
        t.three();
    }
}
```

ouput is 0 and 3
but it should be 3 and 3

Comment: what language is this? your code snippet should not even compile

Comment: You must provide real code or we cannot help you do anything.

Comment: I just edited the code

Comment: I spaced out your code for some better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `new SomeType(..)` then at first `new` creates instance of `SomeType` class *with fields set up to its [**default** values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* (for `int` it is `0`, for `boolean` `false`, for object references `null`).

Proper initialization of object is done later via ***constructor*** code. This is why code responsible for initializing fields is moved at start of each constructor (after `super()` call since code in subclasses often depends on supperclass settings). So

```
class Child extends Super {
    int three = (int) Math.PI;  // That is, 3
```

is compiled as

```
class Child extends Super {
    int three = 0;//initialization to proper value is moved to constructors
                  //                                   |
    Child(){      //                                   |
        super();  //                                   |
        three = (int) Math.PI;  //<--------------------+
    }
    ...
}
```

Because `super()` is invoked before proper initialization of `three` field, its value is still set to `0`.

Constructor of superclass invokes `three();` method but since it was overridden in Child class, because of [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), code of `Child#three` is invoked. Since that code is printing value of `three` and proper initialization didn't happen yet, you are seeing as first its default value `0` (set by `new` operator).

After constructor finished his job you called `three();` *second time* via `t.three();`. At that point `three` is properly initialized to `3` (result of `(int) Math.PI;`) so you are seeing `3`.

---

To avoid such problems don't use in constructors methods which can be overridden in subclass. Either use fields directly, or use private, final or static methods.

Comment: does this case will follow with interface, as we know interface dont have constuctor and in case of interface how it happen ?

Comment: @shiv "interface dont have constuctor" true, but also lets not forget that we can't *instantiate* interfaces. We can only instantiate non-abstract classes so I am not sure what problem you have in mind regarding interfaces.

Comment: @shiv If you want you can ask new, separate follow-up question about it where you describe your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

If you step through this, `three()` will always be the child class's method (your implementation in `Super` will never be called).

Also, the first call to `three()` in `Super()` will actually run before the rest of the constructor for `Child`, hence the reason that the first call is 0 (the child object's not fully initialized yet).